# How can i add mp3 to multimedia player on Android?

Tags: java, android

How can i run multimedia scanner in android? My application download files to SDCARD/Music , but when i run the standard music player, i can't found new mp3. When I restart my phone, music player see my new mp3.

Comment: I update the answer,check it once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  MediaScannerConnection , it is possible to find the new mp3 .This service wants to binds the client service that means your connection.(You have to forcibily scan the file..) .For more information look [here](http://rameshandroidworld.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/how-to-scan-the-new-file-in-android-2/).

```
     private MediaScannerConnection conn;
            private String newFilePath = "New File Path";

            conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {

                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            if (path.equals(newFilePath)) {
                                Log.i("Scan Status", "Completed");
 conn.disconnect();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                              conn.scanFile("path of the new file", null);

                        }
                    });
            conn.connect();
```

Comment: thank you. Now I'm checking your code :)